# Create WordArt programatically in Office 2013 using interop \ VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, com-interop

I need to be able to insert word art programmatically in Office 2013. I cant use [AddTextEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shapes.addtexteffect%28v=office.15%29.aspx) because its useful to insert only Old WordArt and not new ones. I can see they have added  msoTextEffect31 to msoTextEffect50 in MsoPresetTextEffect. But, I cant seem to be able to use them. It does look like, for new WordArt, Word adds a TextBox and then formats the text. Do I have to do this manually for every WordArt style? I have cross-posted the question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9ecd41e6-90bd-4f33-b927-c8d90c24bc54/insert-new-wordart-object-programattically?forum=worddev)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants a workdaround, I have posted one on following thread -
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9ecd41e6-90bd-4f33-b927-c8d90c24bc54/insert-new-wordart-object-programattically?forum=worddev